# passing a string with white-spaces through a function in c++

Tags: string, class, c++11, getline

I have a class named blabla.

```
class blabla  
{    
public:          
      void setName(const string &);    
}

blabla toe;//creating an object
```

Now,

```
string foe;

cin>>foe;

toe.setName(foe);//works completely fine
```

but,

```
string loe;

getline(cin,loe);

toe.setName(loe);//compiles but the program overflows whenever this function is accessed..
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/ITJF57229). Show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When does the program overflow, exactly? Since passing the string as `const &` is trivial, it has to be *inside* `setName`, not on call.

Comment: And by the way, how are the title of the question and the problem related? Do you mean you can't reproduce the problem if `cin`'s line doesn't contain whitespace on `getline`?